# Difference between 'derives from' and 'prompted by'

Tags: differences

Let's imagine we have a task and this task has a child task. 
So what's the difference in relation between parent task and child task if the child task has status:

- Derives from
- Was prompted by

Translation to the native language gives me pretty similar understanding, so I want to clarify the difference.

Comment: I think you need to study up on "object-oriented" principles and "inheritance".  You can't apply everyday definitions of "parent", "child", "task", "derive", etc to computer entities -- you must learn the jargon.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your context is a computer process. *derives from* clearly indicates that the child prcessor has an ansestor,the parent process and inherits some properties from it. *prompted by* seems to vaguely indicate that the parent created a child, but it is not a good usage of this word. In computer jargon I would use *spawned* or *instantiated* instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Context is about defects. Some code has been written (parent task) and someone has found the defect (child task).